# Remove cinnamon & nemo completely

Tags: unity, apt, nautilus, cinnamon, nemo

Yesterday I installed `cinnamon` and `nemo` but didn't like it (don't ask me why).

I am using unity now and I has no reason to remove cinnamon but now when I launch nautilus from terminal, I get this error:

```
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 1.4.0

Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare'
returned error 255: info_fn: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/files is not a
well formed usershare file.

info_fn: Error was Path is not a directory.
```

This is the first time I am seeing this error, and I think removing cinnamon & nemo will solve the problem (But I want to remove it anyway).

So, `sudo apt-get autoremove cinnamon nemo` shows that only ~7MB space will be freed, while ~70MB was downloaded. Where's the rest of space? And how do I solve that nautilus problem?

Comment: Yes you have to remove using `autoremove` once removed you have to execute this command to completely remove it with configuration files : `sudo apt-get --purge remove cinnamon`. Sometime you need to execute same command two-three times to completely remove the packages.. Try it it will remove `cinnamon` completely.. Reply..

Comment: `--purge remove cinnamon` after `autoremove nemo cinnamon` didn't do anything. But running `autoremove nemo cinnamon` again removed additional 23MB. But the nautilus problem is still not solved. It says some problem with `nautilus-dropbox` but dropbox share is working fine :/

Comment: I told you na! sometimes you have to execute same commands two three times.. It happened with me many times.. Good to know you solved your problem..

Comment: A quick restart solved the nautilus problem too. But I am still left with `gnome` which was installed with cinnamon (I think :P).  Any way to remove that too?

Comment: Were you trying to remove cinnamon while using cinnamon? You have to logout and login with `Unity-shell` and completely remove all the configuration files of cinnamon. To do so execute this command : `find . | grep cinnamon | xargs rm -r -f`. Then restart your system once..

Answer (score 1):

Cinnamon and Nemo has several dependencies that other packages that you might have installed use:

```
apt-cache depends cinnamon nemo
cinnamon
  Depends: gir1.2-clutter-1.0
  Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-muffin-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0
  Depends: gir1.2-soup-2.4
  Depends: libatk1.0-0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcairo2
  Depends: libcanberra0
  Depends: libclutter-1.0-0
  Depends: libcogl-pango12
  Depends: libcogl12
  Depends: libcroco3
  Depends: libdbus-glib-1-2
  Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  Depends: libgirepository-1.0-1
  Depends: <libgjs0-libmozjs185-1.0>
    libgjs0c
  Depends: libgjs0c
 |Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx
  Depends: <libgl1>
    libgl1-mesa-glx
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-4
  Depends: libgnome-keyring0
  Depends: libgnome-menu-3-0
  Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
  Depends: libjson-glib-1.0-0
  Depends: libmozjs185-1.0
  Depends: libmuffin0
  Depends: libnm-glib4
  Depends: libnm-util2
  Depends: libpango1.0-0
  Depends: libpolkit-agent-1-0
  Depends: libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0
  Depends: libpulse0
  Depends: libstartup-notification0
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libxfixes3
  Depends: libxml2
 |Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend
  Depends: <gsettings-backend>
    dconf-gsettings-backend
  Depends: gconf2
    gconf2:i386
  Depends: python
  Depends: cinnamon-common
  Depends: gnome-session-bin
  Depends: gjs
  Depends: gnome-settings-daemon
  Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas
  Depends: gnome-icon-theme-symbolic
  Depends: gkbd-capplet
  Depends: gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gconf-2.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gkbd-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-cogl-1.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0
  Depends: gir1.2-pango-1.0
  Depends: gir1.2-polkit-1.0
  Depends: gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0
  Depends: gir1.2-caribou-1.0
  Depends: gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-webkit-3.0
  Depends: libjs-jquery
  Depends: python-gconf
  Depends: python-lxml
  Depends: python-dbus
  Depends: python-imaging
  Depends: python-pyinotify
  Depends: mesa-utils
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
    multiarch-support:i386
  Recommends: gnome-control-center
  Breaks: gnome-control-center
  Breaks: gnome-control-center:i386
  Conflicts: cinnamon:i386
nemo
  Depends: desktop-file-utils
    desktop-file-utils:i386
  Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas
  Depends: gvfs
  Depends: libglib2.0-data
  Depends: nemo-data
  Depends: shared-mime-info
    shared-mime-info:i386
  Depends: libatk1.0-0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcairo-gobject2
  Depends: libcairo2
  Depends: libexempi3
  Depends: libexif12
  Depends: libgail-3-0
  Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgnome-desktop-3-4
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
  Depends: libnemo-extension1
  Depends: libnotify4
  Depends: libpango1.0-0
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libxml2
  Suggests: eog
 |Suggests: evince
  Suggests: <pdf-viewer>
    acroread-bin:i386
    okular
    epdfview
    evince
    evince-gtk
    gv
    viewpdf.app
    xpdf
    zathura
 |Suggests: totem
  Suggests: <mp3-decoder>
    mpg123
    mpg321
    opencubicplayer
    vlc
    vlc-nox
  Suggests: xdg-user-dirs
  Recommends: eject
    eject:i386
  Recommends: gvfs-backends
    gvfs-backends:i386
  Recommends: librsvg2-common
  Recommends: <nemo-fileroller>
  Conflicts: nemo:i386
```

So to remove them you must remove them one by one checking that no other packages has **explicit dependency** of them. Non explicit dependencies are *Recomends* and *Suggests*.

About the error it might be that you (or Cinnamon/Nemo) have shared a directory that it couldn't share and now you are seeing this "error". The solution is find what directory is this renaming it or just drop the sharing as stated [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1244815&p=7815367#post7815367).